# Source Model for Catalog product tye

Tags: magento2, system.xml, source-model

I am creating a bespoke extension and I want to allow the admin to choose to restrict by product types eg Simple, Configurable, Bundle etc

The issue is I am not sure what source model to use.

I have the following code in my system.xml

```
<field id="product_types" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
   <label>Product Type</label>
   <source_model></source_model>
   <comment>Restrict defined product types</comment>
</field>
```

Could anyone advise which source model I need to use so that the options in the multi-select are the product types eg Simple, Configurable, Bundle etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom source model as describe below.

Assume, your are using custom extension name "**Vendor_Module**"

File : **ProductType.php** under ***app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Source***

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Source;

class ProductType implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
    //*
    // @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypeList
    //
    protected $_productTypeList;

    //*
    // Constructor
    //
    // @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypeList
    //
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypeList $productTypeList
    )
    {
        $this->_productTypeList = $productTypeList;
    }

    /**
    * Get options
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options[] = ['label' => '', 'value' => ''];         
        $productType = $this->_productTypeList->getProductTypes();

        foreach ($productType as $pType) {
            $options[] = [
                'label' => $pType->getName(),
                'value' => $pType->getLabel(),
            ];
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

update your **system.xml** as follows.

File : system.xml:

```
    ............................
<field id="product_types" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <label>Product Type</label>
    <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Source\ProductType</source_model>
    <comment>Restrict defined product types</comment>
</field>
    ............................
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks just surprised i have to create a custom source model